Advanced Installer - is it possible to have a prerequisite be installed from the user's local machine?
I have a number of prerequisites for my application, which are specified in the "Prerequisites" page in Advanced Installer.
However, I don't want to include these in the installer package itself - I am trying to reduce the size of the installer -  but I can guarantee that they will be already on the user's machine when they install the application (and I'm happy for it to just error out if not...)
Is there a way of telling it to "Look on user's machine in this location", rather than include it in the package? I see 3 options:

... but they don't seem to address my requirement. ("Use files from disk" seems to be about where Advanced Installer itself sources the files in order to include in the package)
Edit:
I realise I could use a custom action to run a powershell script to perform this task, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing, e.g. from the existing "Prerequisites" feature.

How are they getting into the Prerequisites list?  If they are automatically added, can you remove them?  If you're adding them, try not doing so.

I don't want to remove them completely, I want the installer to detect if they're not installed and install them - but to grab their installers from the user's local machine rather than having them contained within the package.
